Group vector character values into one row/sentence
Is it possible to convert values in a vector into a combined sentence?
I would like to make this

into a single vector with all values combined into a sentence (aka no "" in between each value)
V3_ =c("0", "Org", "48.93", "Si", "0", "Sa", "3.01", "Gr", "9.08", 
"Co", "0", "Ru", "38.58", "Bo", "0.4", "Be")


paste(V3_, collapse = " ")
